# Separating SQLAlchemy mapping class from functional class in python

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm sure there have been questions about this before, and I'm just not searching for the right keywords...

Is it considered good/bad practice to separate ORM mapping classes from the classes that are used for processing in an application?

For instance:

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, name, age, genre):
        self.name  = name
        self.age   = age
        self.genre = genre
        self.score = None # Calculated in real-time, never stored to DB

class ArtistM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "artists"
    name          = Column(String(50))
    age           = Column(Integer)
    genre         = Column(String(50))
```

Conceivable benefit would be to keep the classes used by the primary application completely free of ORM stuff. For instance, assume I've created an Artist class and an entire suite of tools which operate on that class. Later on, I want to start handling LOTS of these objects and decide to add a DB component. Do I want to go back and modify the original Artist class or make new mapping classes on top?

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance to achieve this:

```
# Option-1: use ArtistM everywhere
class ArtistM(Artist, Base):
    # ...

# Option-2: use Artist everywhere
class Artist(ArtistM):
    # ...
```

I prefer option 1 as it does not *blotter* your *pure* classes with the persistent related information. And in your code you could even import them with *pure* names so that you could use your other code interchangably:

```
from mypuremodule import Artist
# or
from mymixedinmodule import ArtistM as Artist
# then use 'Artist` everywhere
```